# LDAP not preventing disabled users from authenticating

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have an interesting situation where we have the exact same application running in a "Development" environment and another in a "Testing" environment behaving differently when authenticating with AD via LDAP.  The behavior is we want LDAP to throw an Authentication Exception if a user tries to authenticate with a disabled account.  In Development this works exactly as expected and we get a error as defined below (data code = 533):

https://web.archive.org/web/20190811215552/http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21290631

When we run this code in the Testing environment however it lets the disabled user login fine.  Clearly something is configured differently with LDAP/AD in each environment right?  If so what setting controls this behavior?

Comment: Do you have multiple domain controllers in the testing environment and are they replicating? (`repadmin /showrepl`)

Comment: We are not replicating in the test environment.

Comment: so, just to make sure - both applications are using the same LDAP source? - sounds like kerberos or local caching to me. - you don't say how the app is integrated is it ldap bind or dir sync?

Comment: I'm more or less authenticating as shown in this documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html

Comment: try disabling local user credential caching https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172931

Comment: We have caching enabled on both servers so I am not sure how that could be a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug with Microsoft AD and Guest Account, fix is disabling the guest account.

[Guest Accounts on AD Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696360/active-directory-allows-creating-initialcontext-with-disabled-account)

Comment: I don't really see this as a bug per se. It's likely a combination of the way JNDI handles LDAP binding and the default settings of AD allowing anonymous (aka Guest) binds. Disabling the guest account is just a hacky way to disallow anonymous binds. You can do it more elegantly with group policy.